# Complex Room many-to-many relation with regex key matching

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

I have two tables in a Room database, one containing `Device.class` entities, the other `Message.class`; each device might be related to zero, one or many messages, and equally each message might have a relation with multiple devices (at least one). The two tables are updated independently, Device on user input, Message from the network.

Being the relation between `Device` and `Message` based on MQTT topic pattern, I need to match the two via regex to account for wildcards, therefore I cannot employ Room's `@Relation` annotation with keys (at least, as far as I understood).
I am looking for a way to fetch `LiveData<List<DeviceWithMessages>>` to feed to the UI, which must be updated when either of the two underlying entity changes.

Device.class looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Device {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int uid;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    public String name;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "topics")
    public List<String> topics;
}
```

Message.class:

```
@Entity
public class Message {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
    public int topic;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "value")
    public String value;
}
```

The topic stored in the `Message` object will look something like `a/b/c/d`, and the list in the `Device` class may contain strings like `a/b/*/d`, `a/w/*/d`, etc. In this example, `a/b/c/d` and `a/b/*/d` would be matched via regex, `a/w/*/d` would not have a match.

Things that I have taken into consideration so far:

1. Relations vie the `@Relation` annotation, but looking at documentation and previous answers it seems like it cannot handle more complex cases where a regex match is required.
2. Storing `Device`/`Message` ids in a third table and referencing it to retrieve messages for the interested devices; would rather not employ this solution an keep things simple. Moreover, messages still need to be matched somehow upon arrival to determine the corrispondance with the stored devices.
3. Joining the two class via an `INNER JOIN` in the dao query; in this regards, I have two problems, the first one being that I am not too confident with raw sql queries, the second one is that I am not totally sure that I can regex-match against a list of strings retrieved from a table, something like `'WHERE topic REGEXP device.topics'` (??).
4. Combining LivaData objects into one, such that messages are matched with the corresponding Device before being delivered to the UI. With this approach the problem is that when a device is updated, references to its messages are lost.
   For this, I am trying `MediatorLiveData`:

```
public static LiveData<List<Device>> getCombinedLiveData(LiveData<List<Device>> devices, LiveData<Message> messages) {
        MediatorLiveData<List<Device>> liveDataMerger = new MediatorLiveData<>();

        liveDataMerger.addSource(devices, newList -> {
            if (newList != null) liveDataMerger.setValue(newList);
        });

        // Messages live data; retrieves only the latest incoming message to avoid matching again each device with every stored message
        liveDataMerger.addSource(messages, newMessage -> {
            Single.fromCallable(() -> {
                List<Device> list = liveDataMerger.getValue();
                if (list == null) return null;

                for (Device device : list) {
                    List<String> deviceTopics = device.getTopics();

                    for (String topic : deviceTopics) {
                        if (MqttTopic.isMatched(topic, newMessage.getTopic())) {
                            device.messages.put(topic, newMessage.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return list;
            })
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .doOnError(Timber::e)
                    .subscribe(liveDataMerger::setValue);

        });
        return liveDataMerger;
    }
```

Where `device.messages` is an `HashMap<String, String>` (<topic, message>).

With regards to this approach, I will try to handle a list of `DeviceWithMessages.class` objects instead of `List<Device>` within `MediatorLiveData` to try to avoid loosing messages value when the data in `LiveData<List<Device>>` changes. In any case, I fear this is causing a pointless high computational load despite being run in the background, moreover considering that there might be a case where ~100 devices are defined and receiving messages from ~200 topics, and would rather not use it.

5. Running something equivalent to what reported before in a dao `@Transaction`.
6. Lastly, what I am currently using for testing out other functionalities: intercepting messages directly from the network client before even being saved to the database and matching them against the existing devices:

```
// called directly from the network client
private void onMessageArrived(String messageTopic, String message) {
        Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            List<Device> allDevices = database.dao.getAllDevices();

            for (Device device : allDevices) {
                List<String> deviceTopics = device.getTopics();

                    for (String deviceTopic : deviceTopics) {
                        if (MqttTopic.isMatched(deviceTopic, messageTopic)) {
                            device.messages.put(deviceTopic, message);
                            database.dao.update(device);
                        }
                    }
            }
            return null;
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .doOnError(Timber::e)
                .subscribe();
}
```

which is effectively the same done before, with the addition of saving the device in the database with a copy of the message stored in an `HashMap`.
In this way, fetching devices from the database returns an updated list of corresponding messages without any need for joins/queries on the other table. As before, I don't like this solution, which moreover do not keep devices and messages separated.

So, would like to hear suggestion from someone more experienced in sql/Room or ideas of possible approaches. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create 3 table : Device, Topic , Message.
It will clear and easy to query.